# How to search in HAPI FHIR using reverse chaining and AND operations?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I have a list of Schedules. Each Schedule have many related Slots. Each Slot has an specific date and status, which can be free or busy.

I want to search all Schedule that have free Slots in a specific date. E.g, I want to get all Schedules with free slots on 2023-12-06. Is it possible to do it with only one query?

At this moment I've already got:
`/Schedule?_has:Slot:schedule:start=2023-12-06&_has:Slot:schedule:status=free`

But this search has a major flaw: it get Schedules with Slots at 2023-12-06 OR free Slots, and this is not what I want.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is the expected behavior of [Reverse Chaining](https://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#has) - specifically that each `_has` operator is evaluated independently.  You do have a few options:

1. filter the results client-side

Since the results are over-broad, the client is not missing data.  The client can filter through the results and reduce down to the desired set.

2. define a custom `composite` search parameter

You can define a new [SearchParameter](https://hl7.org/fhir/searchparameter.html) for the `Slot` resource.  If the search parameter is a `composite` type with the parts `start` and `status`, the evaluation will be joined together.  I believe you will need to issue a re-index on HAPI, but it is good about that.  For example, if the composite parameter was coded as `start-status`, your search could look like:
`Schedule?_has:Slot:schedule:start-status=2023-12-06$free`

3. Use the `_filter` parameter

Using the [_filter](https://hl7.org/fhir/search_filter.html) parameter gives more flexibility in general, at the cost of more complex query-building.  I believe HAPI supports `_filter` out-of-the-box, but I am not completely sure.  Based on your earlier query, I *think* a filter-based one would look something like:
`Schedule?_filter=(_has:Slot:schedule:start eq 2023-12-06 and _has:Slot:schedule:status eq free)`

4. Define a Named Query

More complex but even more flexible, you can define a [Named Query](https://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#advanced) to get the search results you want.  Similar to defining a search parameter, except that you define an operation (using [OperationDefinition](https://hl7.org/fhir/operationdefinition.html)) and then search using the name of the operation.

Hope this helps, cheers!
-Gino

Comment: I agree with what Gino has said. But I have another option: if there is no extra filter needed on the Schedule resource, the query could be done on Slot and including the Schedule resources: Slot?start=2023-12-06&status=free&_include=Slot:schedule
You do get the Slots in your Bundle as well, but you could ignore those and focus on the included Schedules